# Django remove all default migration

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to remove all default django migration?

My app doesn't use any of the default migration so I think it's a good idea to remove all unused migration

Comment: You can remove all the `INSTALLED_APPS` that you don't require

Comment: What are default migrations?

Comment: @daniherrera it creates these tables https://i.imgur.com/2bRgDPp.png

Comment: @Sayse ohh.... Thanks man

Comment: ok, you are telling about remove apps you don't need, the whole app, not just the migrations.

Comment: you means Old Migrations

Comment: @Sayse I did remove auth and then got the error when trying to migrate:  `RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.auth.models.Permission doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all migrations except `migrations/__init__.py`.

If your production migrations are your local migrations, don't touch anything, or do the same in production as well.